# Selenium WebDriver JAVA: How to click at x,y coordinates?

Tags: java, flash, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am not able to click a Point in Flash Player, I have a Flash Iframe Embedded in browser , and I want to click on certain Button, Since its tough for me to code for Flash and communicate with Flash Elements.

So, i want to click (1170,230) , assuming 0,0 is top left corner of browser Page(Excluding Address and bookmark Bar)

I am using follwing code , However it is not working.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

WebElement knownElement1=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*@id='game']")));

Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver); 
builder1.moveToElement(knownElement1, 1170, 230).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you switch to this flash frame?

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frameWebElementInstance);
```

Don't forget to switch back, if you'll be doing sth outside of the frame

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
int xScrollPosition= 0; //enter your x co-ordinate
int yScrollPosition= 0; //enter your y co-ordinate

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("YOUR LOCATOR"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("window.scroll(" + xScrollPosition + ", " + yScrollPosition + ");");
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Some modification to your code:                                                                  

1). executor.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(1170,230)");                                   

2). The last line of your code is not understandable , what is the element here?